# Protobuf missing 'list' suffix in Objective-C generated code

Tags: objective-c, protocol-buffers, automatic-ref-counting, objective-c-2.0, manual-retain-release

I'm using protobuf 2.6.1 with [this plugin](https://github.com/minyushov/Protobuf-ObjC) which I compiled myself.

In the project I'm working with Protobuf models are already present. I tried to regenerate the files using the following command:

protoc --plugin=/path/to/the/compiled/plugin/objc-gen --objc_out=./gen/  NAME.proto OF.proto THE.proto FILES.proto

Generally, the files match closely with the previously generated models, however, there are some syntactic differences.

The following .proto string:

```
repeated MyType case = 4;
```

is translated to this line in Obj-C (New plugin, with ARC):

```
@property (readonly, strong) NSArray * case;
```

And it used to be with the `List` suffix (Old plugin, non-ARC, doesn't work with the current version of macOS):

```
- (NSArray*) caseList;
```

Given that `case` is a keyword in Objective-C, this triggers compilation errors.

Questions:

1. **Since what version Protobuf changed syntax to omit `List` suffix?**
2. **Is it possible to trigger "old" behavior with a new plugin?**
3. **What is the last version of plugin that runs on macOS 10.14.3 and
   able to generate the files with old style (i.e. with the `list`
   suffix)?**